# how to force partial view to render proper url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview, razor-2

ASP.NET MVC4 search Razor partial view is defined as

```
@inherits ViewBase<MvcMusicStore.ViewModels.SearchViewModel>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Browse", "Store" , FormMethod.Get,
    new { @class = "searchform" }))
{

    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Search, new
{
    @class = "searchfield",
    value = "Search..."
})
    <input class="searchbutton" type="submit" value="@("Search...")" />
    <input type="hidden" value="relevance" name="order" />
}
```

and used in site.cshtml:

```
@Html.Partial("Search", new MvcMusicStore.ViewModels.SearchViewModel())
```

If page address is `http://localhost:52223/Store/Browse/Kuupakkumine`  search form is created with invalid action /Store/Browse/Kuupakkumine. Kuupakkumine is automatically added to end of url:

```
<form action="/Store/Browse/Kuupakkumine" class="searchform" method="get">
 <input class="searchfield" id="Search" name="Search" type="text" value="Search...">    
<input class="searchbutton" type="submit" value="Search...">
</form>
```

How to fix this so that correct url, `/Store/Browse` will appear in browser html ?

Storecontroller Browse method signature is

```
[OutputCacheAttribute(VaryByParam = "*", Duration = 0, NoStore = true)]
public ActionResult Browse(string category, string order, int? page, bool? descending,
 int? itemsPerPage, string brand, string color, string @class, string type, bool? grid,
    string search, bool? instock, CartLayout? cartLayout, string id)
```

Comment: What is the signature of the method?

Comment: I dont understand question, which method signature ? `Html.BeginForm` in MVC builtin method

Comment: The controller method - `public ActionResult Browse( what are the parameters? )`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I updated question and added Browse signature Default routing is used so Kuupakkumine is passed as Id parameter to Browse and this returns invalid result. id must be null if Browse is called from Search. Only search parameter must filled for Browse

Comment: Assuming your using the default route, then `Html.BeginForm("Browse", "Store", new { id = "" }, FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "searchform" }))`

Comment: Thank you. It worked. you may wrote it as answer. Why id is automatically passed ? Is default query string always passed if BeginForm is used without query string parameter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your using the default route (`url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",`) and your `Browse()` method includes a matching `string id` parameter which means that the value of `id` is added as a route value. The `BeginForm()` method uses these values to generate the forms `action` attribute. This behavior is useful because if you are (say) creating a form to edit a model, and that model contains a property `int ID`, then it is not necessary to include a hidden input for the `ID` property.

To override the default behavior, you need to explicitly set the route value to `null`

```
Html.BeginForm("Browse", "Store", new { id = "" }, FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "searchform" }))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the route, probably you have a default route that matches /Store/Browse/Kuupakkumine (/{Controller}/{Action}/{id}).

Try to create a new rote without id, put a specific name on it and use inside your Partial like this.

```
routes.MapRoute("Search", "{Controller}/{Action}");
```

And in your Partial use it.

```
Html.BeginForm("Search")
```